# An error about "this"

Tags: javascript, this

```
  var orders=document.getElementsByClassName("order");
for(var i=0;i<orders.length;i++){
    orders[i].index=i;
    orders[i].onclick=function(){
        console.log(orders[i].index);
    }
}
```

The error like this:

[image]

But when I change the code like this:

```
var orders=document.getElementsByClassName("order");
    for(var i=0;i<orders.length;i++){
        orders[i].index=i;
        orders[i].onclick=function(){
            console.log(this.index);
        }
    }
```

The error disappeared,and what I am  confused about is that  **this** ==**orders[i]**  as we know, but why when I use `orders[i].index`, it wrongs?

Comment: because `i === orders.length` by the time `orders[i].onclick` is executed

Comment: yeah,you are right.I tried to console log the "i",and the last value of "i" is "undefined".Thank you for answering my first question,haha

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.order', function () {
      console.log($( ".order" ).index( this ));
});
```

```html
 <div class="order ">product info</div>
<div class="order">product info</div>
<div class="order">product info</div>
<div class="order">product info</div>
<div class="order">product info</div>
```